# ssrs sum function in textbox

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have 2 datasets in my report. And I need to put a number of rows that meet a certain condition in a text box.

Here's what I have so far:

```
=Sum(IIF((Fields!OPEN_TIME.Value, "calls")=Parameters!Date.Value,1,0))
```

I get following error while running the report:
**The Value expression for the text bix uses an aggregate expression without a scope. A scope is required for all aggregate used outside of a data region unless the report contains exactly one dataset**

What do I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here if you are specifying a dataset name to a field like this "(Fields!OPEN_TIME.Value,"calls")" its a syntax error.. if you are using the field in a table which is assigned to dataset1 and table is assigned to dataset2 or field in a text box, then the field should be used with aggregate or "First", "Last" 
Example:
first(Fields!OPEN_TIME.Value, "calls") 
last(Fields!OPEN_TIME.Value, "calls") 
sum(Fields!OPEN_TIME.Value, "calls") 
Count(Fields!OPEN_TIME.Value, "calls") ...etc 
In above scenario rather than taking a textbox, take a table with single cell assign the dataset "calls" to it then go for below expression:
=Sum(IIf(Fields!OPEN_TIME.Value = Parameters!Date.Value, 1,0))